# Would a Raspberry Pi be feasible for use on a CubeSat?

Tags: hardware

I am putting together a cubesat for propulsion testing, and will be going to orbit early 2018. I need to put this one together for a cheap as possible, while having some decent power. The next one will be more customized.

So, here is my question, I was originally wanting to go RPi, with an Arduino shield to control the entire system, as it'll be a mix of analog & digital sensors. I am thinking of using Kube OS (RT version). They have used STM3F24 and the MSP430 the most, looks like those are the boards used most in the industry for flight computers and etc. As I said, I was looking to go RPi, or if I hit issues, Edison, as I have experience with both.

What do you guys suggest? Would a Pi Zero handle an RT OS well? I am looking at the RPi dual compute modules for my next cube, but it is too much right now. Any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Related https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1046/19949